# How to remove specific duplicates in R

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
> head(bigdata)
      type                               text
1  neutral              The week in 32 photos
2  neutral Look at me! 22 selfies of the week
3  neutral       Inside rebel tunnels in Homs
4  neutral                Voices from Ukraine
5  neutral  Water dries up ahead of World Cup
6 positive     Who's your hero? Nominate them
```

My duplicates will look like this (with empty `$type`):

```
7              Who's your hero? Nominate them
8           Water dries up ahead of World Cup
```

I remove duplicates like this:

```
bigdata <- bigdata[!duplicated(bigdata$text),]
```

The problem is, it removes the wrong duplicate.  I want to remove the one where `$type` is empty, not the one that has a value for `$type`.

How can I remove a specific duplicate in R?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? I can't replicate your problem. `bigdata[!duplicated(bigdata$text),]` gives me the correct rows with the data frame I created.

Comment: @KaraWoo I can't really explain - it wasn't working before - but now it seems to be working correctly, as you describe.  I guess I can close this question?

Answer (score 2):

So here's a solution that does not use `duplicated(...)`.

```
# creates an example - you have this already...
set.seed(1)   # for reproducible example
bigdata <- data.frame(type=rep(c("positive","negative"),5),
                      text=sample(letters[1:10],10),
                      stringsAsFactors=F)
# add some duplicates
bigdata <- rbind(bigdata,data.frame(type="",text=bigdata$text[1:5]))   

# you start here...
newdf  <- with(bigdata,bigdata[order(text,type,decreasing=T),])
result <- aggregate(newdf,by=list(text=newdf$text),head,1)[2:3]
```

This sorts `bigdata` by text and type, in decreasing order, so that for a given text, the empty `type` will appear after any non-empty `type`. Then we extract only the first occurrence of each type for every `text`.

---

If your data really is "big", then a `data.table` solution will probably be faster.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(bigdata)
setkey(DT, text, type)
DT.result <- DT[, list(type = type[.N]), by = text]
```

This does basically the same thing, but since `setkey` sorts only in increasing order, we use `type[.N]` to get the *last* occurrence of `type` for a every `text`. `.N` is a special variable that holds the number of elements for that group.

---

Note that the current development version implements a function `setorder()`, which orders a `data.table` *by reference*, and can order in both increasing and decreasing order. So, using the [devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), it'd be:

```
require(data.table) # 1.9.3
setorder(DT, text, -type)
DT[, list(type = type[1L]), by = text]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = function(x){
    x == ""
}

bigdata <- bigdata[-(!duplicated(bigdata$text)&sapply(bigdata$type, foo)),]
```

Comment: Probably also want to check if it's duplicated with `fromLast=TRUE`.

Comment: $type missing = white space, NA, NULL? Just insert the corresponding check and opt `fromLast` as mentioned by @josilber

Comment: I initialize `$type` to `type = ''` so I don't know how to check that.

Comment: @Vlo your ! is in the wrong location -- you're limiting to rows that are both non-duplicated and have a missing `type` value, which is why the OP is getting 0 rows from your solution.

Comment: Get an error that says, "Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default"

Comment: Thank you, but it appears my code is working correctly now.  It wasn't working before, but now it seems to work - not sure what happened...

Comment: Try this. sapply(X = bigdata$type, FUN = foo). If you can post a subset of the data with dput(), this would be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep rows that are either not duplicated or not missing a type value. The `duplicated` function only returns the second and later duplicates of each value (check out `duplicated(c(1, 1, 2))`), so we need to use both that value and the value of `duplicated` called with `fromLast=TRUE`.

```
bigdata <- bigdata[!(duplicated(bigdata$text) |
                     duplicated(bigdata$text, fromLast=TRUE)) |
                   !is.na(bigdata$type),]
```

Comment: This seems to give me the same result as what I had before.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @user1477388 without a reproducible example showing your problem it's tough to tell -- post code that gives what you think are the wrong results and describe the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for your help - it appears for some reason that my code wasn't working before, but now it works; maybe an R environment issue or something.